# How can I produce a singular value for the magnitude of a magnetic field based on measurements?

Tags: electromagnetism

In my experiment, I mounted neodymium magnets to an aluminum glider as shown in the image below.

[image]

I used a Vernier Magnetic probe to measure the intensity of the field at various points on the inside of the glider by treating it as a coordinate system. How can I obtain a singular value for the magnitude of the field from the magnet based on this data?

Comment: What do you mean singular value, as a single value of the field everywhere? That's not possible because as you should see the field changes from location to location because it's a vector field.

Comment: It might help to know for what purpose you need this value. I'd guess that you're going to investigate the effects of forces between *two* magnet-carrying gliders, but that's only a guess.